# How to open fancybox pop-up view images outside of an iframe which has an image gallery made in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I installed a php gallery and configured it and I finally could make it to run inside an iframe.But now when I click at an image, I want it to open that image pop-up view outside the iframe.[imgGallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjxqi.png)

```html
<?php

if (isset($this->vars['file_list']))
  {
   $thumb_code['file'] = $this->getThumbCode("file");
   
   foreach ($this->vars['file_list'] as $file)
   { 
    $output = '';
    
    $img_url = $this->genThumbURL($request, $file);
    
    if ($this->settings['use_popup_image_viewer'] == true) {
     $url = "?image=" . $request . $file['file'];
     if ($this->settings['show_thumbs_under_viewer'] == true) {
      $fancy_class = "fancybox-thumbs";
      $fancy_attr = "data-fancybox-group=\"thumb\"";
     } else {
      $fancy_class = "fancybox";
      $fancy_attr = "data-fancybox-group=\"gallery\"";
     }
    } else {
     $url = '?view=' . $request . $file['file'];
     $fancy_class = "";
     $fancy_attr = "";
                }
    
    //<<URL>> = $url = ?view=folder/image.jpg
    //<<FANCY_CLASS>> = $fancy_class = fancybox-thumbs (If left out fancybox will not work. Use inside class attribute on A tag)
    //<<FANCY_ATTR>> = $fancy_attr = data-fancybox-group="gallery" (If left out fancybox will not work. Use on A tag)
    //<<TITLE>> = $file['file'] = image.jpg
    //<<THUMB_WIDTH>> = $this->settings['thumb_size_' . $this->vars['thumb_size']] = 125 (autodetect thumb size also)
    //<<THUMB_HEIGHT>> = $this->settings['thumb_size_' . $this->vars['thumb_size']] = 125 (autodetect thumb size also)
    //<<THUMB_LOCATION>> = $this->escapeString($img_url) = phppi/cache/folder/image_small.jpg (may also set to phppi/themes/gallery/themename/images/no_images.png if no image)
    //<<THEME_LOCATION>> = $this->showThemeURL(1) = phppi/themes/gallery/themename
    
    $replace_codes = array("<<URL>>",
     "<<FANCY_CLASS>>",
     "<<FANCY_ATTR>>",
     "<<TITLE>>", 
     "<<THUMB_WIDTH>>", 
     "<<THUMB_HEIGHT>>", 
     "<<THUMB_LOCATION>>", 
     "<<THEME_LOCATION>>"
    );
    
    $replace_values = array($url,
     $fancy_class,
     $fancy_attr,
     $file['file'], 
     $this->settings['thumb_size_' . $this->vars['thumb_size']], 
     $this->settings['thumb_size_' . $this->vars['thumb_size']], 
     $this->escapeString($img_url), 
     $this->showThemeURL(1)
    );

    echo str_replace($replace_codes, $replace_values, $thumb_code['file']);
   }
  }
  
  echo "<div style=\"clear: both;\"></div>\n";
 }
 
 function showPrevFolderURL($format = 0)
 {
  //0 = Output url
  //1 = Return url as string 
  if ($format == 0)
  {
   echo '?' . $this->vars['dir']['req']['parent'];
  } else if ($format == 1) {
   return '?' . $this->vars['dir']['req']['parent'];
  }
 }
 
 function showPrevImageURL($format = 0)
 {
  //0 = Output url
  //1 = Return url as string 
  if ($format == 0)
  {
   if ($this->settings['use_javascript_navigation'] == true)
   {
    echo 'javascript: phppi.go_prev_image();';
   } else {
    if (isset($this->vars['file_list'][$this->vars['previous_image_id']]['full_path']))
    {
     echo '?view=' . $this->vars['file_list'][$this->vars['previous_image_id']]['full_path'];
    } else {
     echo '';
    }
   }
  } else if ($format == 1) {
   if ($this->settings['use_javascript_navigation'] == true)
   {
    return 'javascript: phppi.go_prev_image();';
   } else {
    if (isset($this->vars['file_list'][$this->vars['previous_image_id']]['full_path']))
    {
     return '?view=' . $this->vars['file_list'][$this->vars['previous_image_id']]['full_path'];
    } else {
     return '';
    }
   }
  }
 }
 
 function showNextImageURL($format = 0)
 {
  //0 = Output url
  //1 = Return url as string 
  if ($format == 0)
  {
   if ($this->settings['use_javascript_navigation'] == true)
   {
    echo 'javascript: phppi.go_next_image();';
   } else {
    if (isset($this->vars['file_list'][$this->vars['next_image_id']]['full_path']))
    {
     echo '?view=' . $this->vars['file_list'][$this->vars['next_image_id']]['full_path'];
    } else {
     echo '';
    }
   }
  } else if ($format == 1) {
   if ($this->settings['use_javascript_navigation'] == true)
   {
    return 'javascript: phppi.go_next_image();';
   } else {
    if (isset($this->vars['file_list'][$this->vars['next_image_id']]['full_path']))
    {
     return '?view=' . $this->vars['file_list'][$this->vars['next_image_id']]['full_path'];
    } else {
     return '';
    }
   }
  }
 }
 
 function showUpFolderURL($format = 0)
 {
  //0 = Output url
  //1 = Return url as string 
  if ($format == 0)
  {
   echo '?' . $this->pathInfo($_GET['view'], 'dir_path');
  } else if ($format == 1) {
   return '?' . $this->pathInfo($_GET['view'], 'dir_path');
  }
 }
 
 function showThemeURL($format = 0)
 {
  //0 = Output url
  //1 = Return url as string 
  if ($format == 0)
  {
   echo 'phppi/themes/gallery/' . $this->settings['theme'] . '/' . $this->vars['theme_mode'] . '/';
  } else if ($format == 1) {
   return 'phppi/themes/gallery/' . $this->settings['theme'] . '/' . $this->vars['theme_mode'] . '/';
  }
 }
 
 function showTitle($format = 0)
 {
  //0 = Output url
  //1 = Return url as string
  if ($format == 0)
  {
   echo $this->vars['page_title'];
  } else if ($format == 1) {
   return $this->vars['page_title'];
  }
 }
 
 function showSiteName($format = 0)
 {
  //0 = Output name
  //1 = Return name as string
  if ($format == 0)
  {
   echo $this->settings['site_name'];
  } else if ($format == 1) {
   return $this->settings['site_name'];
  }
 }
 
 function showLogo($format = 0)
 {
  //0 = Output img tag
  //1 = Return img tag as string  
  if ($format == 0)
  {
   echo "<img id=\"page-logo\" src=\"" . $this->settings['page_title_logo'] . "\" alt=\"" . $this->settings['site_name'] . "\">";
  } else if ($format == 1) {
   return "<img id=\"page-logo\" src=\"" . $this->settings['page_title_logo'] . "\" alt=\"" . $this->settings['site_name'] . "\">";
  }
 }
 
 function showNav($format = 0, $home = "", $prev = "", $sep = "", $mode = "") 
 { 
  //Mode:
  //classic = Only show title and previous button
  //new = Breadcrumb style, may take up most of the page if using a large folder tree
  //auto = Depending on theme it may switch between the two depending on the screen size
  //left empty = Set based on user settings
  
  //$home = HTML to insert for home button
  //$prev = HTML to insert for prev button
  //$sep = HTML to insert for seperator
  
  $output = "";
  
  if ($mode == "") {
   $mode = $this->settings['nav_menu_style'];
  }
 
  if ($mode == "auto" || $mode == "new") {
   $new_output = "<ul><li class=\"nav-home\"><a href=\"?\">" . $home . "</a></li>";
   $url = "?";
   
   if ($this->vars['dir']['req']['full'] !== "") {
    $new_output .= "<li class=\"nav-sep\">" . $sep . "</li>";
   
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($this->vars['dir']['req']['split'] as $value) {
     if ($i < (count($this->vars['dir']['req']['split']))) {
      $url .= $value . "/";
      $new_output .= "<li><a href=\"" . substr($url, 0, -1) . "\">" . $value . "</a></li>";
      $new_output .= "<li class=\"nav-sep\">" . $sep . "</li>";
     } else {
      $new_output .= "<li class=\"nav-curr\"><div class=\"title\">" . $value . "</div></li>";
     }
     
     $i++;
    }
   }
   
   $new_output .= "</ul>";
  }
  
  if ($mode == "auto" || $mode == "classic") 
  {
   $url = "?";
   
   if ($this->vars['dir']['req']['parent'] !== "") {   
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($this->vars['dir']['req']['split'] as $value) {
     if ($i < (count($this->vars['dir']['req']['split']))) {
      $url .= $value . "/";
     }
     
     $i++;
    }
    
    $url = substr($url, 0, -1);
   }
   
   $classic_output = "<ul><li class=\"nav-prev\"><a href=\"" . $url . "\">" . $prev . "</a></li>";
   if ($this->vars['dir']['req']['curr'] !== "") {
    $classic_output .= "<li class=\"nav-sep\">" . $sep . "</li>";
    $classic_output .= "<li class=\"nav-curr\"><div class=\"title\">" . $this->vars['dir']['req']['curr'] . "</div></li>";
   }
   $classic_output .= "</ul>";
  }
  
  if ($mode == "auto") {
   $output .= "<div class=\"nav-menu-new\">" . $new_output . "</div>";
   $output .= "<div class=\"nav-menu-classic\">" . $classic_output . "</div>";
  } else if ($mode == "new") {
   $output = $new_output;
  } else if ($mode == "classic") {
   $output = $classic_output;
  }
  
  //0 = Output nav
  //1 = Return nav as string  
  if ($format == 0)
  {
   echo $output;
  } else if ($format == 1) {
   return $output;
  }
 }
 
 function showPage()
 {
  require($this->showThemeURL(1) . 'pages/' . $this->vars['page_requested'] . '.php');
 }
 
 function resizedSize($width, $height, $return = 2)
 {
  //Returns width, height or an array of width and height for the thumbnail size of a full sized image  
  if ($width > $height)
  {
   $new_height = $this->settings['thumb_size_' . $this->vars['thumb_size']];
   $new_width = $width * ($this->settings['thumb_size_' . $this->vars['thumb_size']] / $height);
  } else if ($width < $height) {
   $new_height = $height * ($this->settings['thumb_size_' . $this->vars['thumb_size']] / $width);
   $new_width = $this->settings['thumb_size_' . $this->vars['thumb_size']];
  } else if ($width == $height) {
   $new_width = $this->settings['thumb_size_' . $this->vars['thumb_size']];
   $new_height = $this->settings['thumb_size_' . $this->vars['thumb_size']];
  }
  
  if ($return == 0)
  {
   //Return width
   return floor($new_width);
  } else if ($return == 1) {
   //Return height
   return floor($new_height);
  } else if ($return == 2) {
   //Return array with width and height
   return array(floor($new_width), floor($new_height));
  }
 }
 
 function insertHeadInfo()
 {
  echo "
<!-- 
PHP Picture Index " . $this->vars['version'] . "

Created by: Brendan Ryan (http://www.pixelizm.com/)
Site: http://phppi.pixelizm.com/
Licence: GNU General Public License v3                      
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/                
-->\n\n";

  echo "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable = no; maximum-scale=1.0;\">\n";
  if (isset($_GET['view']) && !isset($this->vars['error'])) {
   echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"phppi/scripts/jquery/jquery.js\"></script>";
  } elseif ($this->settings['use_popup_image_viewer'] == true) {
   echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"phppi/scripts/jquery/jquery.js\"></script>\n";
  }
  
  if (isset($_GET['view']) && !isset($this->vars['error']))
  {     
   if ($this->settings['page_title_show_full_path'] == true) { $temp_title_full_path = '1'; } else { $temp_title_full_path = '0'; }
   if ($this->settings['enable_hotkeys']) { $enable_hotkeys = 1; } else { $enable_hotkeys = 0; }
   if ($this->settings['enable_up_hotkey']) { $enable_up_hotkey = 1; } else { $enable_up_hotkey = 0; }
   
   echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"phppi/scripts/phppi_js.js\"></script>   
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
 $(document).ready(function() { phppi.initialize(); });
 
 phppi.image_width = " . $this->vars['file_list'][$this->vars['current_image_id']]['data'][0] . ";
 phppi.image_height = " . $this->vars['file_list'][$this->vars['current_image_id']]['data'][1] . ";
 phppi.up_folder = '" . $this->escapeString($this->showUpFolderURL(1)) . "';
 phppi.prev_image = '" . $this->escapeString($this->showPrevImageURL(1)) . "';
 phppi.next_image = '" . $this->escapeString($this->showNextImageURL(1)) . "';
 phppi.title_full_path = " . $temp_title_full_path . ";
 phppi.enable_hotkeys = " . $enable_hotkeys . ";
 phppi.enable_up_hotkey = " . $enable_up_hotkey . ";";
   
   if ($this->settings['use_javascript_navigation'] == true)
   {
    $file_list = "";
    $x = 0;
    
    $dir = $this->pathInfo($_GET['view'], 'dir_path');
    
    foreach($this->vars['file_list'] as $file) {
     $file_list .= "['" . $this->escapeString($dir) . "/" . $this->escapeString($file['file']) . "', '" . $this->escapeString($file['file']) . "', " . $file['data'][0] . ", " . $file['data'][1] . "]";
     
     if ($x < (count($this->vars['file_list']) - 1)) { $file_list .= ","; }
     
     $x++;
    }
    
    echo "
 phppi.site_name = '" . $this->settings['site_name'] . "';
 phppi.page_title = '" . $this->vars['page_title'] . "';
 phppi.current_file = " . $this->vars['current_image_id'] . ";
 phppi.files = [" . $file_list . "];";
   }
   
   echo "</script>\n";
  }
  
  if ($this->settings['use_popup_image_viewer'] == true)
  {
   echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"phppi/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js\"></script>\n";
   if ($this->settings['show_thumbs_under_viewer'] == true) { echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"phppi/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js\"></script>\n"; }
   if ($this->settings['enable_mousewheel'] == true) { echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"phppi/scripts/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js\"></script>\n"; }
   
   if ($this->settings['show_thumbs_under_viewer'] == true) {
    //Thumb Helper Version
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
   openEffect: '" . $this->settings['open_image_animation'] . "',
   closeEffect: '" . $this->settings['close_image_animation'] . "',
   prevEffect: '" . $this->settings['nextprev_image_animation'] . "',
   nextEffect: '" . $this->settings['nextprev_image_animation'] . "',
 
   closeBtn: false,
   arrows: false,
   nextClick: true,
 
   helpers: {
    thumbs: {
     width: " . $this->settings['popup_thumb_size'] . ",
     height: " . $this->settings['popup_thumb_size'] . "
    }
   }
  });
 });
</script>\n";
   } else {
    //Normal Version
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fancybox').fancybox({
   openEffect: '" . $this->settings['open_image_animation'] . "',
   closeEffect: '" . $this->settings['close_image_animation'] . "',
   prevEffect: '" . $this->settings['nextprev_image_animation'] . "',
   nextEffect: '" . $this->settings['nextprev_image_animation'] . "'
  });
 });
</script>\n";
   }

   echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"phppi/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css\">\n";
   if ($this->settings['show_thumbs_under_viewer'] == true) { echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"phppi/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css\">\n"; }
  }
  
  echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"phppi/css/global.css\">\n";
  echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"phppi/themes/thumbnail/" . $this->settings['thumbnail_theme'] . "/style.css\">\n";
  echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"" . $this->showThemeURL(1) . "style.css\">\n";
 }
 
 function initialize()
 {  
  //Debug Mode  
  if ($this->settings['debug_mode'] == true)
  {
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  }
  
  ini_set('memory_limit', $this->settings['php_memory'] . 'M');
  
  //Set Thumb Size if changed
  if (isset($_POST['thumb_size'])) {
   if ($_POST['thumb_size'] == 0) { 
    $this->setThumbSize('small');
   } else if ($_POST['thumb_size'] == 1) { 
    $this->setThumbSize('medium');
   } else if ($_POST['thumb_size'] == 2) { 
    $this->setThumbSize('large');
   }
  } else {
   $this->setThumbSize(NULL);
  }
  
  //GZIP Compression
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', $this->settings['use_gzip_compression']);
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression_level', $this->settings['gzip_compression_level']);
  
  //Theme Mode
  $this->setThemeMode();
  
  if ($this->settings['allow_mobile_theme'] == true)
  {
   if (!is_file('phppi/themes/gallery/' . $this->settings['theme'] . '/' . $this->vars['theme_mode'] . '/template.php'))
   {
    $this->vars['theme_mode'] = 'standard';
   }
  } else {
   $this->vars['theme_mode'] = 'standard';
  }
  
  //Load Variables
  $this->loadVars();
  
  //Load Blacklists/Whitelists
  $this->loadLists();
  
  //Display Content
  if (isset($_GET['thumb'])) 
  {
   //Show thumbnail only
   $this->genThumbnail($_GET['thumb']);
   
   exit;
  } else if (isset($_GET['image'])) {
   //Show image
   if ($this->checkExploit('/' . $_GET['image']) == true) {
    $file_ext = strtolower($this->pathInfo($_GET['image'], 'file_ext'));
    
    if ($file_ext == 'jpg' or $file_ext == 'jpeg')
    {
     $format = 'jpeg';
    } else if ($file_ext == 'png') {
     $format = 'png';
    } else if ($file_ext == 'gif') {
     $format = 'gif';
    }
    
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($this->vars['dir']['gallery'] . '/' . $_GET['image']));
    header("Content-type: image/" . $format);
    readfile($this->vars['dir']['gallery'] . '/' . $_GET['image']);
   } else {
    echo "File doesn't exist.";
   }
   
   exit;
  } else if (isset($_GET['view'])) {
   //Show full image view
   $req_path = $this->pathInfo($_GET['view'], 'dir_path');
   
   if ($req_path !== "") { $req_path = "/" . $req_path; }
   
   if ($this->checkExploit($req_path) == true) {
    if (!$this->getDir($req_path . '/'))
    {
     $this->vars['error'] = 'Folder doesn\'t exist';
     $this->vars['page_title'] = 'Error';
     $this->vars['page_requested'] = 'error';

     $this->logs("access", "add", "Folder not found (/" . $_GET['view'] . ")");
    } else if (!is_file($this->vars['dir']['gallery'] . '/' . $_GET['view'])) {
     $this->vars['error'] = 'File doesn\'t exist';
     $this->vars['page_title'] = 'Error';
     $this->vars['page_requested'] = 'error';
     
     $this->logs("access", "add", "File not found (/" . $_GET['view'] . ")");
    } else {
     for($i = 0; $i < count($this->vars['file_list']); $i++)
     {
      if ($this->vars['file_list'][$i]['file'] == $this->pathInfo($_GET['view'], 'full_file_name'))
      {
       $this->vars['current_image_id'] = $i;
       $this->vars['previous_image_id'] = NULL;
       $this->vars['next_image_id'] = NULL;
       
       if ($i > 0)
       {
        $this->vars['previous_image_id'] = $i - 1;
       }
       if ($i < (count($this->vars['file_list']) - 1))
       {
        $this->vars['next_image_id'] = $i + 1;
       }
       
       break;
      }
     }
     
     if ($this->settings['page_title_show_full_path'] == true) {
      $this->vars['page_title'] = $this->settings['site_name'] . " - " . str_replace("/", " \ ", $_GET['view']);
     } else {
      $this->vars['page_title'] = $this->settings['site_name'] . " - " . $this->pathInfo($_GET['view'], 'full_file_name');
     }
     $this->vars['page_requested'] = 'image';
     
     $this->logs("access", "add", "Viewed image (/" . $_GET['view'] . ")");
    }
   } else {
    $this->vars['error'] = 'File doesn\'t exist';
    $this->vars['page_title'] = 'Error';
    $this->vars['page_requested'] = 'error';
    
    $this->logs("access", "add", "Possible exploit attempt, blocked access (/" . $_GET['view'] . ")");
   }
   
   require('phppi/themes/gallery/' . $this->settings['theme'] . '/' . $this->vars['theme_mode'] . '/template.php');
   
   if ($this->settings['debug_show_vars'] == true) { $this->outputVarsArray(); }
   if ($this->settings['debug_show_settings'] == true) { $this->outputSettingsArray(); }
  } else {
   //Show folder view 
   if ($this->vars['dir']['req']['full'] == '')
   {
    $dir_req = "";
   } else {
    $dir_req = $this->vars['dir']['req']['full'] . '/';
   }
   
   if ($this->vars['dir']['req']['full'] == '' || $this->checkExploit('/' . $this->vars['dir']['req']['full']) == true) {
    
    if (!$this->getDir($dir_req))
    {
     $this->vars['error'] = 'Folder doesn\'t exist';
     $this->vars['page_title'] = 'Error';
     $this->vars['page_requested'] = 'error';
     
     $this->logs("access", "add", "Folder not found (/" . $dir_req . ")");
    } else {
     if ($this->settings['page_title_show_full_path'] == true) {
      if ($this->vars['dir']['req']['full'] == "") { $sep = ""; } else { $sep = " - "; }
      $this->vars['page_title'] = $this->settings['site_name'] . $sep . str_replace("/", " \ ", $this->vars['dir']['req']['full']);
     } else {
      if ($this->vars['dir']['req']['full'] == "") { $sep = ""; } else { $sep = " - "; }
      $this->vars['page_title'] = $this->settings['site_name'] . $sep . $this->vars['dir']['req']['curr'];
     }
     $this->vars['page_requested'] = 'folder';
     
     $this->logs("access", "add", "Viewed folder (/" . $dir_req . ")");
    }
   } else {
    $this->vars['error'] = 'Folder doesn\'t exist';
    $this->vars['page_title'] = 'Error';
    $this->vars['page_requested'] = 'error';
    
    $this->logs("access", "add", "Folder not found or exploit attempt, blocked access (/" . $dir_req . ")");
   }
   
   require('phppi/themes/gallery/' . $this->settings['theme'] . '/' . $this->vars['theme_mode'] . '/template.php');
   
   if ($this->settings['debug_show_vars'] == true) { $this->outputVarsArray(); }
   if ($this->settings['debug_show_settings'] == true) { $this->outputSettingsArray(); }
  }
 }
}
?>
```

How to add or turn this jQuery or Javascript code into php to modify this fancybox to open images outside of the iframe?

```js
<script>
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.imagen').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
parent.$.fancybox([
{href:'img/sample-9.jpg', title: '01'},
{href:'img/sample-9.jpg', title: '02'},
{href:'img/sample-9.jpg', title: '03'}
],{
//   href: this.href,
   helpers: {
    overlay: {
    opacity: 0.3
    } // overlay
    //, buttons: {}
   } // helpers
  }); // fancybox
 }); // click
 
   //or in this way using another way or option
    $('.image').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  parent.$.fancybox({
   href: this.href,
   width: 560,
   height: 315,
   type: 'iframe',
   helpers: {
    overlay: {
    opacity: 0.3
    } // overlay
   } // helpers
  }); // fancybox
 }); // click

beforeClose: function() {
$(".fancybox-inner").unwrap();
},
   helpers: {
    overlay: {
    opacity: 0.3
    } // overlay
   }
}); //fancybox
return false;
}); //click 
}); // ready
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

This problem is similar to this example:[Example Demo](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxFromIframe_16Jan12.html)
I am in the iframed page 01 situation and I want to do something similar to 
iframed page 02.

Answer (score 2):

Your page inside `<iframe>` is limited to the shape of iframe. Period.

First what comes to my mind is this. In order to display something *bigger* than iframe you would have to have some script outside your iframe, and then have some communication between iframe contents and page with iframe (most likely with [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)).

Other idea would be going with your gallery full screen with [FullscreenAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), and then you would have all screen to yourself. In case of gallery that could lead to some nice effect. Just remember, to be able to do that, `<iframe>` that displays your gallery has to has attribute `allowfullscreen` (no value needed).

In both cases you will need to be able to either add additional JavaScript outside iframe, or control how iframe is added to page. This is security measure so the contents of iframe will not *abduct* the parent page.